# Im stuck at grub menu and cant boot to Ubuntu!

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

So I used boot repair and got rid of all old kernels and then I restarted My Toshiba satellite and didn’t get the regular menu entries like before where I can just pick an image and boot into Ubuntu. Now it just gives me the

> minimal bash-like line editing… Tab lists possible command completions…

with this in the next line.

```
grub>
```

I don’t know what to do here I read online some things to try in order to get back to Ubuntu but nothing has worked. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 4):

Type the following commands & change disk partition according to your system.

```sh
ls
set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub #note: maybe (hd0,2) or (hd0,3)
set root=(loop0)
set
ls /boot
insmod /boot/grub/linux.mod
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro #note: maybe sda2 or sda3 to match #2 above.
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

When you get Ubuntu booted running `update-grub` should fix the problem. For more details visit http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. However, when I put that info into grub> it says no server is specified and that I have to load the kernel first

Comment: First type `ls` command to list all disk drivers. 
According to the disk partition, change the command and try it.

Comment: I did exactly that and after ls /boot, it tells me no server is specified. Is that a good thing?

Comment: After `insmod /boot/grub/linux.mod` I get `error: file /boot/grub/linux.mod not found.`

Answer (score 2):

With a little tweaking I got this working.

Here's what I did:

```
Grub> ls
```

I got the different partitions.

```
Grub> ls (hd0,msdos1)
```

this showed me the files on my HDD, so this is the correct partition for me.
Then I did:

```
Grub> set root=(hd0,msdos1)
Grub> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
Grub> set
Grub> ls /boot #this returned a list of files/folders in /boot
Grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
Grub> initrd /initrd.img
Grub> boot
```

After a few minutes of doing it's thing, grub booted into the busybox shell, where I was able to run `fsck /dev/sda1` and a couple presses of 'y' later, Ubuntu booted like normal!

Comment: Thanks. Just 2 lines I had to change were:
`Grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1`, 
`Grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img`
But then, before it booted in Busybox, I got `ALERT! /dev/sda1 does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Following Zach's steps I got this error after booting in Busybox

```
ALERT! /dev/sda1 does not exist
```

I then needed to run:

```
> blkid
```

Which gave me the actual name of my volumes. In my case, the one I needed was called `/dev/nvme0n1p9` (source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kilXfY-k_9A)

So the instuctions I had to run where:

```
Grub> set root=(hd0,gpt9)
Grub> set prefix=(hd0,gpt9)/boot/grub
Grub> set
Grub> ls /boot #this returned a list of files/folders in /boot
Grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/nvme0n1p9
Grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img
Grub> boot
```